# Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "/listtask" - line 141, col 67)

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try build CRUD with Spring boot and Thymeleaf template. I got an error while writing the form to create a new task in the listtask.html file - line 141, column 67

Here is my code

Task.class

```
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TaskID")
    private short id;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "`Status`")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "Content")
    private String content;

    public Task() {
    }


    public Task(short id, String title, String status, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.status = status;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

TaskController.class

```
    @Autowired
    private ITaskService taskService;


    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String showListTasks(Model model) {

        List<Task> tasks = taskService.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("tasks", tasks);

        return "/listtask";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String showNewTaskForm(Model model){
        Task task = new Task();
        model.addAttribute("task", task);
        return "/listtask";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTask(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task) {
        taskService.save(task);
        return "/listtask";
    }

    @GetMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String ShowUpdateTaskForm(@PathVariable("id")short id, Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("listtask");
        Task task = taskService.findById(id);
        modelAndView.addObject("task", task);

        return "/listtask";
    }
```

listtask.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todo List </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrapicons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Import js -->

    <script th:src="@{/js/Program.js}"></script>

    <!-- Import css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/Modal.css}">

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/task/list}">Todo List</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="Register.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="LoginPage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Export CSV</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" onclick="openAddModal()" ><i class="fa fa-plus"> Tạo mới</i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-inline">
                    <input class="form-control mr-ms-2" type="search" placeholder="Từ khóa" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" >Tìm kiếm</button>
                    <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline-block">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="position: relative; display: inline-block">Status<span class="carset"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <li><a href="#">Open</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Inprogress</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Done</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tiêu đề</th>
                <th>Trạng thái</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="task : ${tasks}">
                <td th:text="${task.title}"></td>
                <td th:text="${task.status}"></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="detail" title="Detail" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>Administration</td>
                <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter Parker</td>
                <td>Customer Service</td>
                <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fran Wilson</td>
                <td>Human Resources</td>
                <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr> -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Tạo mới task </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="modal-container">

                        <!--                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">-->
                        <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${task}">
                            <label for="create-title"><b>Title</b></label>
                            <input class="title-label-input-create-task" id="create-title" name="create-title"
                                   placeholder="Nhập vào tiêu đề" th:field="*{title}" >


                            <label for="status" id="status"><b>Status</b></label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="form-control" id="status_form" >
                                    <option>--Trạng thái--</option>
                                    <option th:value="OPEN" th:text="Open"></option>
                                    <option th:value="INPROGRESS" th:text="Inprogress"></option>
                                    <option th:value="DONE" th:text="Done"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <label for="content"><b>Content</b></label>
                            <br>
                            <textarea name="content" rows="4" cols="50" class="content-textarea" id="content" >
                            Mô tả
                        </textarea>
                        </form>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- success alert -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert" style="display: none;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
        <strong>Success! </strong>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Program.js"></script>
</html>
```

log

```
2022-08-03 00:09:05.281 ERROR 16692 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "/listtask": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//listtask.html]")
```

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//listtask.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1404) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1148) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1087) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "/listtask" - line 141, col 67)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "/listtask" - line 141, col 67)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlVoidElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlVoidElement.java:92) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'task' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Line 141, col 67 where is "th:field=*{title}" i think it's ok but something wrong.
Please! I need some help!

Comment: I see `@GetMapping("/list")` and `@RequestMapping("/list")`. Which of those is being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that there is no `task` object in your model for this line in your html `<form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${task}">`

With what you've given this can come from a variety of reason, for example you have both a `@GetMapping("/list")` and `@RequestMapping("/list")` and plain `@RequestMapping` catches all types including Get. Maybe this should be `@PostMapping`?

Also your save function returns the thymeleaf file without model attributes that it needs. Maybe you intent to redirect here like so `return "redirect:/{PathPrefixes}/list"`? thos would send a new call to your get method that does have model attributes and refreshes the page